# does anyone know this question about' module 'mpctools' has no attribute 'getCasadiFunc''?

Tags: python, mpc

my mpctools version is '0.9.0'
it seems that mpctools doesn't work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8p3s.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoTEC.png)

thanks if someone know about 'mpctools'

Comment: Please do not post images of code/errors. [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: this module have many dependencies, have you confirmed during installation that all the dependencies have been installed successfully?

Comment: import casadi, mpctools as mpc    f = mpc.getCasadiFunc(ode, [Nx, Nu], ["x", "u"], rk4=True, Delta=dt, M=4)  sorry,codes in the images is above.mainly about the reference of 'mpctools'

Comment: opencv-python
scikit-learn
matplotlib
seaborn
pandas
pathos
scipy
numpy
numba,those dependencies have been installed.thanks if anyone know where the method'getCasadiFunc' depends on .